# Godaddy API GET all domains and print automation, printing null

Tags: java, godaddy-api

Currently trying to automate a GET all my Godaddy domains, using their API(BTW I am using IntelliJ ultimate). I am currently getting a response and everything is running fine it seems, apart from when I try to print out for example all the names of the domains, it just prints out "Null". Below is my code:

```
public class GoDaddyGET {


    Properties prop = new Properties();


    public void getData() throws IOException {

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\nerdi\\FableMedia\\src\\main\\java\\files\\env.properties");
        prop.load(fis);

        //prop.getProperty("HOST");
    }


    public void Test(){

        // write your code here

        //BaseURL or Host
        RestAssured.baseURI = prop.getProperty("GODADDYHOST");

        Response res = given().
                header("Authorization", prop.getProperty("GODADDYKEY")).log().all().
                header("Content-Type", "application/json").
                header("Accept", "application/json").
                param("includes", "contacts").
                when().
                get(Resources.godaddyGetData()).
                then().assertThat().statusCode(200).
                and().
                contentType(ContentType.JSON).
                and().
                body("array[0].domain",equalTo("SENSITIVE INFORMATION")).
                and().
                body("array[0].domainId",equalTo("SENSITIVE INFORMATION")).
                and().
                header("Server", "SENSITIVE INFORMATION").log().body().

                extract().response();


        JsonPath js = ReusableMethods.rawToJson(res);

        int count = js.get("array.size()");

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            String name = js.get("array["+i+"].domain");
            System.out.println(name);
        }
        System.out.println(count);

    }
}
```

And below is my terminal output:

```
Request method: GET
Request URI:    https://api.godaddy.com/v1/domains?includes=contacts
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: includes=contacts
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    <none>
Path params:    <none>
Headers:        Authorization=sso-key APIKEY:APISECRET
                Accept=application/json
                Content-Type=application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cookies:        <none>
Multiparts:     <none>
Body:           <none>
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
23

===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Ive done this the exact same way with google maps, where it works as intented.

## UPDATE 1

Below is part of the Json response:

```
[ { "domainId": SENSITIVE INFORMATION, "domain": "SENSITIVE INFORMATION", "status": "ACTIVE", "expires": "2018-08-13T06:37:31Z", "expirationProtected": false, "holdRegistrar": false, "locked": true, "privacy": true, "renewAuto": true, "renewable": true, "transferProtected": false, "createdAt": "2015-08-13T06:37:31Z" },
```

Can't paste the entire thing here cuz its too long. However its basicly this 22 more times (23 total), but obv. with different info.

Comment: How does the json from the GoDaddy response looks like ?

Comment: [
    {
        "domainId": SENSITIVE INFORMATION,
        "domain": "SENSITIVE INFORMATION",
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "expires": "2018-08-13T06:37:31Z",
        "expirationProtected": false,
        "holdRegistrar": false,
        "locked": true,
        "privacy": true,
        "renewAuto": true,
        "renewable": true,
        "transferProtected": false,
        "createdAt": "2015-08-13T06:37:31Z"
    },
    Can't paste the entire thing here cuz its too long. However its basicly this 22 more times (23 total), but obv. with different info

Comment: Added it to original post for better readability

Comment: @Kable Hey I'm trying to handle cURL requests in Java, particularly eclipse, do you know a way of incorporating that? I am new and have no particular experience whatsoever in anything but Java. I saw that your question was similar

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works.

```
    DocumentContext js = JsonPath.parse(res);
    JSONArray domains = js.read("$..domain");
    for(int i = 0; i < domains.size(); i++)
        System.out.println(domains.get(i));
```

Take your raw response object `res` and create DocumentContext

```
DocumentContext js = JsonPath.parse(res);
```

Read all the domains in a JSONArray

```
JSONArray domains = js.read("$..domain");
```

Then iterate over

```
for(int i = 0; i < domains.size(); i++)
    System.out.println(domains.get(i));
```

Comment: I added this:
DocumentContext raw = com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.parse(res);

        JSONArray domains = raw.read("$..domain");
        for (int i = 0; i < domains.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(domains.get(i));
        }

BUT nothing really changed except for another line in the terminal which reads:
16:39:00.470 [main] DEBUG com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath - Evaluating path: $..['domain']